# How to send an email with the status of the scheduled tasks in Windows scheduler in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to send an email with the updated status of the scheduled tasks set in Windows scheduler in Power Shell.

I am able to get the updated status of the scheduled tasks in Powershell via this command:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Lakshmen\schedu
ledTasksResults.csv
```

This exports the data into a csv. Instead I would like this information in an email. But I am not sure how to send this via a email.

Tried this:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Send-MailMessage -To "lakesh@outlook.com" -From "lakesh@outlook.com" -Subject "ScheduledTasks" -SmtpServer "smtp.mail.outlook.com"
```

Got an error like this:

```
Send-MailMessage : Illegal characters in path.
At line:1 char:59
+ ... dTaskInfo | Send-MailMessage -To "lakesh@outlook.com" -From  ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Send-MailMessage], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SendMailMessage
```

Need some guidance on this.

Comment: You seem to be talking about tasks and emails, I don't understand why you mention both things. Is it possible to remove the reference to tasks from your question and make it more focused that way?

Comment: Cite from `Get-Help Send-MailMessage -sh` ***You can pipe the path and file names of attachments to Send-MailMessage .*** What you pipe to the cmdlet can't be interpreted as path/filename so you get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to attach your result from:

```
 Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Path C:\Lakshmen\scheduledTasksResults.csv
```

**Edit** due to correct comment by @LotPing that [spaltting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) (less is more) should be used instead of the variables (thanks).

Then sending the mail:

```
$Arguments = @{
    From = "lakesh@outlook.com"
    To = "lakesh@outlook.com"
    Attachment = "C:\Lakshmen\scheduledTasksResults.csv"
    Subject = "Here are my scheduled tasks"
    Body = "See the attachments for the tasks results"
    SMTPServer = "smtp.mail.outlook.com"
    SMTPPort = "587"
}

Send-MailMessage @Arguments -UseSsl -Credential (Get-Credential) –DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess
```

Or you could simply put it into the body:

```
$Arguments = @{
    From = "lakesh@outlook.com"
    To = "lakesh@outlook.com"
    Subject = "Here are my scheduled tasks"
    Body = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Out-String
    SMTPServer = "smtp.mail.outlook.com"
    SMTPPort = "587"
}

Send-MailMessage @Arguments -UseSsl -Credential (Get-Credential) –DeliveryNotificationOption OnSuccess
```

Note: due to the `Get-Credential` it will prompt you for password.  If you want it without user interaction you need to store your password it as `SecureString`.

Answer (score 1):

First create a credential object. Then make sure to convert the object to string in order to be able to be sent. Personally I would send the CSV as attachment, but here is an example:

```
$emailAddress = "lakesh@outlook.com"
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString "yourPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$mycreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("$emailAddress", $secpasswd)
$tasks = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath "\" | Get-ScheduledTaskInfo | Out-String

Send-MailMessage -To $emailAddress -From $emailAddress -Subject "ScheduledTasks" -SmtpServer "smtp.mail.outlook.com" -Credential $mycreds -Body $tasks
```